# How to create a custom theme for SXA using SXA CLI (Sitecore 9.3)?

Tags: node.js, sitecore

I've been trying to install SXA CLI for Sitecore 9.3 nd I keep getting the following error when I run the gulp command:

Requiring external module @babel/register
ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
at fs.js:27:26

Bsed on a few articles, I have created the file npm-shrinkwrap.json at the same level as the package.json file and I ran the npm install command. Per the article, npm install should make changes to the file. However, that does not happen. I keep getting the above error.
I have delegted the node_modules folder and run npm install with the same results

Gulp version is:
CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 4.0.2

Node version is:
v12.13.0

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

1. Add a file npm-shrinkwrap.json with the following contents at the location where package.json is located

   ```
    `{
      "dependencies": {
        "graceful-fs": {
          "version": "4.2.2"
        }
      }
   }`
   ```
2. Delete old node_module folder after adding the file.
3. Now run npm-install then.